# R: string ends with one of strings

Tags: r

Is there a more elegant way to find out which elements of a character string vector end with a colon, period or bracket? (Also, I might later want to include question marks etc.)

```
x <- c("2)", "This", "is", "a", "Test:", "Find", "the", "dots.", "Which", "ones")
which(grepl("\\.$", x) | grepl("\\:$", x) | grepl("\\)$", x))
```

Comment: Like `which(grepl("[:.)]$", x))`?

Comment: Since you want indices, just use `grep`, i.e. `grep("[.:)]$", x)`

Comment: Oh man, missed removing the backslashes. Thanks. even faster is:  grep("[.:)]$", x)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, nrussell and docendo discimus.

```
grep("[.:)]$", x)
```